# Replace text in a tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How may I target certain links in list items using Javascript to remove certain characters?
For example I have the following code:

```
<dd class="xments">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">"blah blah",</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">"lo lo",</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">"hhe he"</a></li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

I wish to remove the " and , for each list item. Please could some one help?

```
$("a").text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace('"', '');
    return text.replace(',', '');
});
```

Doesn't seem to do it for me. How do I target only items in this list and not all a tags in the doc?

Comment: return after return won't return

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').each(function (i, e) {
  $(e).text($(e).text().replace(/[",]/g, ''))
});
```

yours with regexp (and additional conditions):

```
$("dd.xments ul li a").text(function(idx, text) {
  return text.replace(/[",]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: yeah, i confused ' and ,

Comment: removed ' from the regexp to only replace " and ,

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").text(function(_, text) {
    var txt=text.replace('"', '');
    txt=txt.replace(',', '');
    this.innerText=txt;

});
```

To target only items in your list, add a class to each item. Change `$("a")` with `$("classname")`

Comment: Just returning `txt` and letting jQuery handle it instead of setting `this.innerText=txt;` would be cleaner

Comment: @megawac - yours is definitely cleaner, the addition of setting class name helps to address replacing only those in this particular list rather than all links on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul li').each(function(){        
        var that = $(this).children();
        var txt = $(that).html();
        txt = txt.replace(/["']/g, '');
        $(that).html(txt.replace(',',''));
    });

});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBAdV/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9scDW/1/)

#### jQuery

```
$("a").text(function(el, text){
    return text.replace(/[",]/g, ''); 
});
```

#### Result

```
blah blah
lo lo
hhe he
```

#### Pattern

```
/[",]/g
```

Here I <kbd>[**Check RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/38ls0)</kbd>